# Linear Regression with coefficient of a, b, c and d?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

First I am a beginner and am trying to understand linear regression. I was reading an article and saw a formula:

```
Power = Irradiance * (A + B * Irradiance + C * Temperature + D * Windspeed)
```

Given the above, the article said that "linear regression is performed on test data to determine constants A, B, C and D". Will someone be able to enlighten me on the constants A to D in a general terms? Will appreciate if someone can point out some website to help me understand linear regression and how to find these constants.

Thank you.

Comment: Linear regression would be more of the form $y=A+Bx_1+Cx_2+Dx_3+\epsilon$ so in your example you might consider $y=\frac{\text{Power}}{\text{Irradiance}}$, $x_1=\text{Irradiance}$, $x_2=\text{Temperature}$, $x_3=\text{Windspeed}$

Comment: Thanks Henry, is this consider a multiple linear regression? If I insert in data into irradiance, temperature and wind speed and apply multiple linear regression method I should be getting the 4 constants? Sorry if it does not make sense to you since I may be thinking/terming it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site.

The equation given is not a good starting example, as it involves multiple interactions.

Rather than a website, I suggest a course - either at a university or online. A second (and less optimal) suggestion would be a good book. It's been a while since I looked for a book on introduction to regression, but I do like e.g. *Regression Analysis by Example* by Chatterjee.

If you've never studied statistics at all, you should start with an introductory course or book. My favorite first book on statistics is *Statistics* by Freedman, Pisani and Purves.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Peter. I am currently attending a university course but it is still 1 year before I start to seriously touch on these. I will really want to understand it, at least a portion of it, prior to learning it in school. Is it fine if you can expand on what you meant by multiple interactions? I assume this will be a multiple linear regression in this case?

Comment: You have one independent variable outside the parentheses.